# PHP fetch value from database and display it in the inside the HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a system where I have a problem I have this code where I just follow inside a youtube video. but change some text. here is my code

```
<label>Department</label>
    <select>
        <?php
        include 'php/connect.php';

        $sql = "SELECT member_type_id FROM member_type";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo "Select a Department";
        while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['member_type_id'] ."'>" . $row['member_type_id'] ."</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

The problem is, It doesn't show me the value inside that table, here is my database table

[image]

the html file is OK, but when I click subit, I always get member registration failed someone correct my code please

```
<?php

include 'php/connect.php';

 $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
 $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
 $Mname = $_POST['Mname'];
 $Bdate = $_POST['Bdate'];
 $Address = $_POST['Address'];
 $Contact = $_POST['Contact'];
 $member_type_id = $_POST['Dept'];
 $Gender = $_POST['Gender'];



 if($Lname == '' OR $Fname == '' OR  $Mname =='' OR  $Bdate == '' OR $Address =='' OR $Contact =='' OR $Gender  =='' OR $member_type_id =='')
{       
            echo "Fill in all the forms";
}


else {



$sql = "INSERT INTO members (Lname, Fname, Mname, Bdate, Dept, Address, Contact, Gender)

VALUES ('$Lname', '$Fname', '$Mname', '$Bdate', 
'$member_type_id', '$Address', '$Contact', '$Gender')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    { 
            echo "A Member has been added successfully";</script>";

    } 
else 
{
```

echo "Member Registration Failed";
    }

```
    }
```

$conn->close();

?>

Comment: Please do not solicit people to reach out to you off of StackOverflow. I went ahead and removed that from your post :)

Comment: what is this `echo "Select a Department";` that doesn't look like valid HTML ie `<select>Select a Department<option .... ></select>` you can't just insert text wily-nilly.  Try `echo '<option value="" >Select a Department</option>';`

Comment: ` <label>Department</label>
        <select>
        <option>Select</option>
            <?php
            mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            mysql_select_db('library_system');

            $sql = "SELECT member_type_id FROM member_type";
            $result = mysqli_query($sql);
            echo "<select member_type_id='sub1'>";
            while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['member_type_id'] ."'>" . $row['member_type_id'] ."</option>";
            }
            ?>
    </select>
    `

here's my new code

Answer (score 1):

Well to start your HTML is invalid, specifically:

```
  echo "Select a Department";
```

This will result in HTML something like this

```
 <select>
     Select a Department
     <option value="1">Faculty</option>
       ...
 </select>
```

Instead echo the first thing as an actual option

```
  echo '<option value="" >Select a Department</option>'
```

So your HTML will be proper

As far as the Query goes, who knows.  Without knowing if you set `$conn` and have a proper connection.

```
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Besides that

```
  $sql = "SELECT member_type_id FROM member_type";
```

Only gives you the number (no one want to select 1, 2 or 3) how will they know 1=Faculty?

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM member_type";
```

Will give you everything, like in PHPmyAdmin. And then:

```
 echo "<option value='" . $row['member_type_id'] ."'>" . $row['member_type'] ."</option>";
```

Will give you the text, assuming your `$conn` variable is a proper connection resource.

Lastly this quoting stuff, is ugly.  Instead do this ( I cant stand single quotes in HTML)

```
 echo '<option value="'.$row['member_type_id'].'">'.$row['member_type'].'</option>';
```

That said if you must use singe quotes, at least use variable interpolation in a sensible way.

```
 echo "<option value='{$row['member_type_id']}'>{$row['member_type']}</option>";
```

One other thing (the thing)

```
    mysql_fetch_array
```

The `mysql_*` set of functions are dead as of PHP7 and there is a huge diffrence between `mysql_` and `mysqli_`.  But on top of that you want `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` as in:

```
 while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

**UPDATE**

Probably the most important thing is turn on display errors and error reporting.  Let PHP tell you what is wrong, why struggle with it.

```
<?php      
  error_reporting(-1);
  ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

Saying `It's not working` or posting a huge block of code in a comment, is not helpful. Programing is hard. It's like math, you have to be exact in what you do or it won't do what you expect.  There are many hundreds of things that can go wrong and typically only a handful of things that will work.

Thanks!

Comment: <?php

 
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "library_system";

$conn = new mysqli ($host, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {

 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

?>

here is my conn.php

Comment: put it in the question, or in backtics `  Such as this `code`

Comment: updated, but it still shows this pretty confusing mix codes

`<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; $dbname = "library_system"; $conn = new mysqli ($host, $username, $password, 
$dbname); 

if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
 die("Connection failed: " . $con>connect_error); } 
?>`

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc`  not `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: updated

`<label>Department</label>
        <select>
        <option>Select</option>
            <?php
            mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            mysql_select_db('library_system');

            $sql = "SELECT member_type_id FROM member_type";
            $result = mysqli_query($sql);
            echo "<select member_type_id='sub1'>";
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['member_type_id'] ."'>" . 
            $row['member_type_id'] ."</option>";
        }
            ?>
    </select>`

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` use `mysqli_` instead.  As of PHP7 `mysql_*` is removed.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: In other words you can't mix `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions, and you should not even be using `mysql_` functions any more as they are being phased out.  I am sure there are a lot of tutorials out there for `mysql_` it's probably `15+` years old at this point, but it's no longer an option as of PHP7+

Comment: here ^_^ thanks still not working
`<label>Department</label>
        <select>
        <option>Select</option>
            <?php
            mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            mysqli_select_db('library_system');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM member_type";
            $result = mysqli_query($sql);
            echo "<select member_type_id='sub1'>";
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['member_type_id'] ."'>" . 
            $row['member_type_id'] ."</option>";
        }
            ?>
    </select>`

Comment: `not working` is  not helpful.  Try turning on error reporting and display errors.  Google it there a a zillion tutorials on it, but if you don't want to, it's simply `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors','1');` at the top of your file.

Comment: at thea header?ill add that line? like this?

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ill add that line inside my header? in the toppest of the code?

Comment: I tried using array and assoc, but the data just wont go inside the database,

Answer (score 0):

Update your connection string

```
<label>Department</label> 
<select name='memberName'> 
    <option>Select</option> 
    <?php 
        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "library_system");
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $sql = "SELECT member_type_id FROM member_type";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        echo "<select member_type_id='sub1'>"; 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['member_type_id'] ."'>" . $row['member_type_id'] ."</option>"; 
        } 
    ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: Yes this  mysqli_fetch_assoc line

Comment: updated code here

`<label>Department</label>
        <select>
        <option>Select</option>
            <?php
            mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            mysql_select_db('library_system');

            $sql = "SELECT member_type_id FROM member_type";
            $result = mysqli_query($sql);
            echo "<select member_type_id='sub1'>";
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['member_type_id'] ."'>" . 
            $row['member_type_id'] ."</option>";
        }
            ?>
    </select>`

Comment: I have updated my answer with updated connection string please check.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below, and you will get the desired results-

```html
<label>Department</label>
<select>
        <option value="">Select a Department</option>
        <?php
        include 'php/connect.php';

        $sql = "SELECT member_type_id, member_type FROM member_type";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['member_type_id'] ."'>" . $row['member_type'] ."</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: it did'nt work, but i change the `=mysql_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_array`

thank you very much ^_^

Comment: where do i put the name? where the databse is going to fetch it from

Comment: include 'php/connect.php'; in this file I suppose

Comment: I still having problem, it wont insert the data, I have a PHP method post

Comment: ohh just check for the mysqli

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?php
include 'php/connect.php';

 $sql = "SELECT member_type_id FROM member_type";
$option = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
  $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['member_type_id'].'">'.$row['member_type_id'].'</option>';
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form>
 <select> 
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```